# Regex expression to search for token not in C++ comment

Tags: regex

I have a code base of thousands of files and need to grep for headers that have a certain token `Q_OBJECT` present but not in a comment. This includes single line `//` comments and multi-line `/* ... */` comments.

What is the regex expression for this search?

Comment: Congratulations at arriving at that conclusion. It's traditional to add a question as well as a statement.

Comment: @Puppy you don't understand the question? I don't get you.

Comment: There is clearly not any question mark in this post.

Comment: @Puppy, that is ridiculous. Are you on a power trip? Anyone would know what the question is.

Comment: There's clearly several possible questions, like "What is the regex", "Is my regex correct", "Where can I find the regex", "Is regex capable of doing this"

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

Do a global search, it will return if it matches
either:

- Comments *group 1*
- Quoted strings, or Non-token text *group 2*
- Token text *group 3*

You just care if capture group 3 matched, it contains the token.

```
   # (/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|(?!Q_OBJECT)[\S\s](?:(?!Q_OBJECT)[^/"'\\])*)|(Q_OBJECT)
   # '(/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\\]|\\\\\n?)*?\n)|("(?:\\\[\S\s]|[^"\\\])*"|\'(?:\\\[\S\s]|[^\'\\\])*\'|(?!Q_OBJECT)[\S\s](?:(?!Q_OBJECT)[^/"\'\\\])*)|(Q_OBJECT)'
   # "(/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\\\]|\\\\\\n?)*?\\n)|(\"(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^\"\\\\])*\"|'(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^'\\\\])*'|(?!Q_OBJECT)[\\S\\s](?:(?!Q_OBJECT)[^/\"'\\\\])*)|(Q_OBJECT)"

   (                                # (1 start), Comments 
        /\*                              # Start /* .. */ comment
        [^*]* \*+
        (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
        /                                # End /* .. */ comment
     |  
        //                               # Start // comment
        (?: [^\\] | \\ \n? )*?           # Possible line-continuation
        \n                               # End // comment
   )                                # (1 end)
|  
   (                                # (2 start), Non - comments 
        "
        (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^"\\] )*        # Double quoted text
        "
     |  '
        (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*        # Single quoted text
        ' 
     |  
        (?! Q_OBJECT )
        [\S\s]                           # Any other char, but not these special tokens
                                         # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                         # or line continuation (escape + newline)
        (?:                              # But not these special tokens
             (?! Q_OBJECT )
             [^/"'\\] 
        )*
   )                                # (2 end)
|  
   (                                # (3 start), Special Tokens
        Q_OBJECT                    
   )                                # (3 end)
```

Comment: This is effectively assuming that Q_OBJECT is a macro, which is not a precondition in the question (it just happens to be true). You might also want to think about raw string literals, universal character sequences/character escapes, and unicode literals.

Comment: I haven't updated this in 10 years. Its not going to be for C++11 I guess. Also, since this regex effectively matches everything, it could be modified in about 10 seconds to find Q_OBJECT any where it needs to be found.

Comment: Note that this could be done without assertions, I was just too lazy.

Comment: Gnu grep 2.5.1 says: `Unmatched ".`

Comment: Also, I think this is line oriented, If `Q_OBJECT` appears in the middle of a multiline comment on a different line from `/*` or `*/` it will it still not match?

Comment: BTW, I didn't mean the parentheses around Q_OBJECT would be part of the search string. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I don't think grep is your friend here. This matches everything, and can span lines. So you must slurp everything in from the file, then check for a group 3 match. So, grep is out of the question, grep is useless for this, however the regex can't be done any other way.